# Права доступа группы для новых файлов

Tags: linux, chmod, права-доступа

Все привет. Есть несколько пользователей, которые по FTP складывают файлы в директорию.
Есть скрипт, который должен читать эти файлы.
У меня возникла проблема с созданием "общей" папки, где пользователи группы имеют rwx права.

**Мои действия:**

1. Создал группу:`sudo groupadd test_group`
2. Установил группу для общего каталога: `sudo chgrp -R test_group /test_dir`
3. Выдал рекурсивные разрешения: `sudo chmod -R 2775 /test_dir`
4. Добавил необходимых пользователей в группы.

**Проблема**.
При создании пользователем файла в директории test_dir права:

```
-rw------- 1 test1 test_group  4096 Aug 25 21:36 321
```

Соответственно условный пользователь test2(в группе test_group)  - не может прочесть файл.

Comment: Проверяйте umask в настройках системы и/или в настройках FTP-сервера

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решил. добавив local_umask=0002 в /etc/vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решил. Добавив local_umask=0002 в /etc/vsftpd.conf